# Jar files for Java to WL Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

What jar(s) do I need to add to handle these imports?

```
com.worklight.server.bundle.api.WorklightBundles
com.worklight.server.integration.api.DataAccessService;
com.worklight.server.integration.api.InvocationResult;
com.worklight.server.integration.api.ProcedureQName;
```

Answer (score 0):

The .jar needed in order to use the mentioned snippet are part of Worklight - so you don't need any additional .jars.

That code is used in order to call an adapter procedure from Java code.
It would look something like this (with proper modifications):

```
import com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject;
import com.worklight.server.bundle.api.WorklightBundles;
import com.worklight.server.integration.api.DataAccessService;
import com.worklight.server.integration.api.InvocationResult;
import com.worklight.server.integration.api.ProcedureQName;

public void callProcedure() {
    DataAccessService service = WorklightBundles.getInstance().getDataAccessService();
    String paramArray = "['param1', 'param2', 'param3']";
    ProcedureQName procedureQName = new ProcedureQName("adapterName",
"procedureName");
    InvocationResult result = service.invokeProcedure(procedureQName,paramArray);
    JSONObject jsonObject = result.toJSON();
    String value = (String)jsonObject.get("key");
}
```

Note though that this is pretty old stuff, and the recommended way is to use Java adapters that were first introduced in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 (I can only assume you're using an older version...).

Read more about adapter types here: [Adapters Overview](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/adapter-framework-overview/)

Comment: I apologize for not being more clear. What I am trying to do is to invoke an adapter from an external java app...not in Worklight..I know how to do this using an adapter url via a browser or via a worklight client, or even using

Comment: essentially trying to call an adapter procedure from an external java app and pass in a JSON object...so I was looking for alternate ways to do this as the only options I have found is to pass in strings. Looks like all of the ways to do this require passing in a string literal. The above method has the same issue.